# Counting total number of records in database according to the ENUM values in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an ENUM with "pending", "resolved", "unresolved" these values, and I want to display the total count of pending records, resolved records and unresolved records, how can I do that in php?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute sql query

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sql = 'SELECT type, COUNT(type) as count_type FROM Table
GROUP BY type';

foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['type'] . ':' . $row['count_type'];
}
```